# Laravel real time chat with websockets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, websocket

Hi I am tring to build a real time chat application with websockets but whenever I try to go visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets I get error 404 not found. I did all the steps like in the documentation so I don't understand what might be the issue:
Followed all the steps here:

```
https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/starting
```

websockets config

```php
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
]
```

.env file

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=anyID
PUSHER_APP_KEY=anyKey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=anySecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the documentation refers there is no line **capacity**
second thing please make sure that you have followed the steps correctly, and make sure you set your **APP_URL** in the .env file properly. Try using **Homestead** or **Valet** as sometimes setting the URL to localhost or 127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't seem to work properly.

I have just did a quick test to check if something might go wrong but all seems to be working just as expected.

[image]

.env file:

```
APP_URL=http://homestead.laravel_websocket
...
PUSHER_APP_ID=moayadapp
PUSHER_APP_KEY=moayadkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=moayadsecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

websockets.php

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
//        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

Comment: is it possible that the port 6001 might be busy, if yes how to fix it?

Comment: If you are not getting and 404 error when navigating to the link then this is nothing to do with PORT is busy, check in websockets.php file this line: **'path' => 'laravel-websockets',**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by running this command

php artisan config:clear